# Mac webview memory leak in OS before 10.12

Tags: macos, memory, webview, operating-system

When I close a NSViewController with a chiled webview, the viewController indeed dealloc and the webview also dealloc, but the occupied App window memory is not entirely release which is consume by webview (every time I open and deallco the webview, the memory only release half). I am tried many solutions from existing answers like

1. load blank page in webview
2. stop loading
3. webview=nil
4. delegate=nil
5. clear cache
6. clear cookies

Comment: What is amazing  is that in OS 10.12 & 10.13, the  occupied window memory by webview  is entirely released.

Comment: - (void)dealloc{
    [self forceReleaseWebViewMemeory];
}

- (void)forceReleaseWebViewMemeory{
    
    self.webView.mainFrameURL = @"";
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadHTMLString:@"<html></html>" baseURL:nil];
    [self.webView stopLoading:nil];
    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
    //[self.webView close];
    self.webView.UIDelegate = nil;
    self.webView.frameLoadDelegate = nil;
    self.webView.resourceLoadDelegate = nil;
    self.webView.policyDelegate = nil;
    self.webView = nil;
}